# Page navigation in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble in identifying the navigation of page numbers. I have the html code like below:

```
<div class="t-numeric">
 <span class="t-state-active">1</span>
 <a class="t-link">2</a>
 <a class="t-link">3</a>
 <a class="t-link">4</a>
 <a class="t-link">...</a>`
</div>
```

This is to navigate to different pages and how can selenium identify 2 or 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Xpath, I don't know which language you use but in C#

```
var page2Locator = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.=\"2\"]"));
```

basically your xpath expression will be

```
//a[.="2"]
```

this is for element  containing text '2' exactly